# What does this bit wise operation doing?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-fields

I read about bitwise operations a lot, but still, I couldn't give a meaning to this line.

```
((text.flags & ~Text.BOLD) & ~Text.ITALIC) | Text.BOLD | Text.ITALIC
```

It seems like the author is trying to be sure that this text doesn't have styles BOLD and ITALIC, and then he makes the text ITALIC and BOLD.

Am I right, or missing some detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be turning off all flags not `BOLD` and not `ITALIC` (via `&` with the complement), and then ensuring that `BOLD | ITALIC` is set (via `|`).

The end result would be that for any input `text` regardless of style, the output is ***text***

Could be re-written as

```
int bold_italic = Text.BOLD | Text.ITALIC;
text.flags = (text.flags & ~bold_italic) | bold_italic;
```

Comment: So as a result, it creates a text that has only BOLD and ITALIC styles.

Comment: It seems so, yes. Certainly, you could test that yourself?

Comment: Or you could just write `text.flags |= bold_italic`

Comment: @Paulpro the other flags are not turned off anyway. `& ~bold_italics` turns off *bold_italics*. It's the same flags that are turned off and then turned on again. If that's not convincing by itself [here](http://haroldbot.nl/?q=%28textflags+%26+~bold_italic%29+%7C+bold_italic) is a step-by-step proof

Comment: Also, if the other flags *were* turned off, the whole thing would simplify to `text.flags = bold_italic`

Comment: @harold You're right, my bad. This answer is wrong, it doesn't turn off all other flags.

Comment: @harold your haroldbot is great. I completely understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

No, you've got it; the `&` operations are erasing the `BOLD` and `ITALIC` bits, while the `|` operations set them.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with 4 bits flag.

`BOLD = 0001;` `ITALIC = 0010`

```
flags & ~BOLD =   
flags & ~0001 = 
flags & 1110 = clear BOLD flag.
```

```
flags | ITALIC = 
flags | 0010 = 
flags | 0010 = set ITALIC flag
```

Comment: ~ operator is actually complement not NOT operator. It's very hard to follow your answer.

Comment: @AlwaysNewbie that's just a different name for the same thing